# Why the SQL Server CE 4 data connection is not listed in the DataConnection combo when I want to generate Database from Model?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am doing some tests with Entity Framework using SQL server CE 4 CTP2 and VS2010 Pro. I can create the data Connection without problems (as administrator) and see the information of the sample database NorthWind.sdf. However when I create a new model (for example persons) and I attempt to generate it into the database NorthWind.sdf using the "generate Database Wizard", I can't see the connection related to "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4". Only Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 and Microsoft SQL Server Database File are listed.

What do you think is happening?

Thanks!!